# Final и static final в java

Tags: java

Просто из "спортивного интереса", что ли.

Вот два класса:

```
class A1
{
    private final int a1 = 1;
}

class A2
{
    private static final int a2 = 2;
}
```

И поле a1, и поле a2 являются константами времени компиляции. Без слова static их объявлять, как мне кажется, смысла не имеет никакого. Но будет ли java для каждого экземпляра класса A1 хранить своё поле a1, или, подумав, компилятор сам от класса A1 "перейдёт" к классу A2?
Какие вообще действия совершает компилятор/интерпретатор при работе с константами времени компиляции для оптимизации?

Answer (score 2):

> Но будет ли java для каждого экземпляра класса A1 хранить своё поле a1

если static, то это общее поле, если нет static - то у каждого объекта свое.

> или, подумав, компилятор сам от класса A1 "перейдёт" к классу A2? 
> это разные классы, поэтому никакого "перейдет".
>
> Какие вообще действия совершает компилятор/интерпретатор при работе с константами времени компиляции для оптимизации?

компилятор может напрячься и выкинуть это поле, подставив фактическое значение по месту. Поэтому, если играть с рефлексией для final полей, могут быть "спецэффекты".